# React JS useState hook not working with curly braces

Tags: reactjs, use-effect, use-state

Can someone explain why this code won't run properly with curly braces around `prev + 1` in the `increment` function?

```
export default function Counter() {
  const [clickCount, setClickCount] = useState(0);

  useEffect(() => {
       document.addEventListener('mousedown', increment);
       return () => {
           document.removeEventListener('mousedown', increment);
      };
   });

   // your code here
  const increment = () => {
      setClickCount((prev) => {prev + 1})
  }

  return (
      <h1>Document Clicks: {clickCount}</h1>
  );
}
```

Comment: Cause you missing `return`. it should be `setClickCount((prev) => {return prev + 1})`.

Answer (score 1):

Arrow function returns expression result by default, but only without that `{}`

If you want to use `{}` remember to add `return`: `(prev) => {return prev + 1}`

Answer (score 0):

```
 setClickCount((prev) => { return prev + 1})
```

you have to return a value for this to work

Comment: The answer is a duplicate of [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73025479/6340959)

Comment: while i was posting this there was no answer tho.

we just posted together

Answer (score 0):

Either you use return statement for existing setClickCount or remove the arrow function and directly update the value.

```
 const increment = () => {
      setClickCount((prev) => {return prev + 1})
  }
```

or

```
const increment = () => {
      setClickCount(clickCount + 1)
  }
```

Jsfiddle link : https://jsfiddle.net/sureshpoosapati/85yhs4r1/1/